# How to Host Laravel-Mix applciation in BigRock?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I am building one application with `Laravel` as back-end and `React.js` as front-end. How to host the application in BigRock or GoDaddy? I searched for 2 days, and found nothing related. Please HELP!!

Comment: https://medium.com/@Bohr/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting-godaddy-953758dc57ac

Comment: But Mix has Node modules in it. Will the reactjs work?

Comment: there would be separate repository for reactjs...correct?

Comment: no, those are inside the project folder

Answer (score 1):

Laravel application hosting don't need something special... just take care of these things.

1. php version as per the desired laravel version.
2. composer should be installed on server.
3. Some pre-dependancies check here... https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation
4. Your domain should point to `<application_root>/public` folder.
5. If you are using `mix` make sure `node` should be installed.

After that..

Just clone / upload the code on server and run the desired commands like..

`composer install` & `npm install` to install the laravel dependancies & node dependancies.

As per your case you are going to host two application here. So you can follow the following approach.

Host laravel application as sub-domain like `api.domain.com` and react application on main domain.

I hope you are already fimilar with what's required for hosting `react` application.

**Edited:**

For the shared hosting, you can request to enabled the `shell access` from hosting provider support team. Once they enabled, you'll able to run the linux command and do install by yourself.

Sometimes they could install required software for you.

All the best!

Comment: Can I install node in shared hosting?

Comment: You can try else. You can contact with their customer support, they could do for you.

Comment: Also check if they could enabled the shell hosting for you... and once you have it.. you can run the linux comand there.

Comment: Just I have got this link on web...hopefully that help to you... https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/